# How to sum total from 3 combobox depending on what a user select in the combobox

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, combobox

I want the user select food from 3 comboBox based on they select the output. For example if they choose rice then it will add 200 and if they choose one more fish(100) then it will calculated the price become 300. The error I have is that my combobox is not calculated though user have selected the output and always display 0

Here is the code

```
public class MainMenu extends JFrame implements ItemListener{
    int total1;
    int total2;
    int total3;
    int total4 = 0;
    JLabel totalconsumed;
    String breakfast_food1[] = {"Add food", "Rice", "Fish", "Egg", "Chicken"};
    int breakfastcalorie1[] = {0, 200, 100, 50, 25};
    String breakfast_food2[] = {"Add food", "Rice", "Fish", "Egg", "Chicken"};
    int breakfastcalorie2[] = {0, 200, 100, 50, 25};
    String breakfast_food3[] = {"Add food", "Rice", "Fish", "Egg", "Chicken"};
    int breakfastcalorie3[] = {0, 200, 100, 50, 25};
    
    public MainMenu() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize( 450, 520);
        setVisible(true);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        
        
        JLabel date = new JLabel("Monday, March 29th 2021");
        date.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        date.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18));
        date.setBounds(77, 11, 259, 14);
        contentPane.add(date);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(SystemColor.activeCaption, 3));
        panel.setBounds(10, 47, 414, 74);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 5, 5));
        contentPane.add(panel);
        
        JLabel calorie_goal = new JLabel("My Calorie Goal");
        calorie_goal.setFont(new Font("Tempus Sans ITC", Font.BOLD, 14));
        panel.add(calorie_goal);
        
        JTextField goal = new JTextField("1500 calories");
        panel.add(goal);
        
        JLabel consumed = new JLabel("Consumed");
        consumed.setFont(new Font("Tempus Sans ITC", Font.BOLD, 14));
        panel.add(consumed);
        
        JTextField total_consumed = new JTextField();
        panel.add(total_consumed);
        
        JLabel remaining = new JLabel("Remaining");
        remaining.setFont(new Font("Tempus Sans ITC", Font.BOLD, 14));
        panel.add(remaining);
        
        JTextField total_remaining = new JTextField();
        panel.add(total_remaining);
        
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        panel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(SystemColor.activeCaption, 3, true));
        panel1.setBounds(10, 240, 415, 80);
        contentPane.add(panel1);
        
        JPanel panel1a = new JPanel();
        panel1a.setBounds(3, 3, 408, 26);
        panel1a.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, 5, 0));
        panel1.add(panel1a);
        
        JLabel breakfast = new JLabel("Breakfast");
        breakfast.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
        panel1a.add(breakfast);
        
        
        JComboBox breakfast1 = new JComboBox(breakfast_food1);
        panel1a.add(breakfast1);
        
        
        JComboBox breakfast2 = new JComboBox(breakfast_food2);
        panel1a.add(breakfast2);
        
        
        JComboBox breakfast3 = new JComboBox(breakfast_food3);
        panel1a.add(breakfast3);
        
        JPanel panel1b = new JPanel();
        panel1b.setBounds(3, 33, 410, 45);
        panel1b.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 5, 5));
        panel1.add(panel1b);
        
        JLabel breakfast_calorie = new JLabel("Recommended Calories");
         breakfast_calorie.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
         panel1b.add(breakfast_calorie);
        
        JTextField breakfast_text = new JTextField();
        breakfast_text.setText("730 calories");
        breakfast_text.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        panel1b.add(breakfast_text);
        
        JLabel breakfast_consumed = new JLabel("Total Consumed");
         breakfast_consumed.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        panel1b.add( breakfast_consumed);
        
        totalconsumed = new JLabel("Total consumed is " + total4);
        panel1b.add(totalconsumed);
        
        
        breakfast1.addItemListener(this);
        breakfast2.addItemListener(this);
        breakfast3.addItemListener(this);
    }
    

    
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e, JComboBox breakfast1, JComboBox breakfast2, JComboBox breakfast3) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            if(source.equals(breakfast1) || source.equals(breakfast2) || source.equals(breakfast3)) {
                total1 = breakfastcalorie1[breakfast1.getSelectedIndex()];
                total2 = breakfastcalorie2[breakfast2.getSelectedIndex()];
                total3 = breakfastcalorie3[breakfast3.getSelectedIndex()];
                total4 = total1 + total2 + total3;
                totalconsumed.setText("Total consumed is  " + total4);
            };
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainMenu();

}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

}
```

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1):

The `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)` method is the one that traps the events from JComboBox. The implementation `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e, JComboBox breakfast1, JComboBox breakfast2, JComboBox breakfast3)` must be linked to it.

To do this

1. Move `breakfast1`, `breakfast2` and `breakfast3` as a instance fields.
2. Instantiate all the three fields inside constructor
3. Change the `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)` method to the following

Here is the complete source code.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class MainMenu extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
    int total1;
    int total2;
    int total3;
    int total4 = 0;
    JLabel totalconsumed;
    String breakfast_food1[] = {"Add food", "Rice", "Fish", "Egg", "Chicken"};
    int breakfastcalorie1[] = {0, 200, 100, 50, 25};
    String breakfast_food2[] = {"Add food", "Rice", "Fish", "Egg", "Chicken"};
    int breakfastcalorie2[] = {0, 200, 100, 50, 25};
    String breakfast_food3[] = {"Add food", "Rice", "Fish", "Egg", "Chicken"};
    int breakfastcalorie3[] = {0, 200, 100, 50, 25};

    //Step 1 - Moved combo boxes to instance fields
    JComboBox breakfast1, breakfast2, breakfast3;

    public MainMenu() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize( 450, 520);
        setVisible(true);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);



        JLabel date = new JLabel("Monday, March 29th 2021");
        date.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        date.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 18));
        date.setBounds(77, 11, 259, 14);
        contentPane.add(date);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(SystemColor.activeCaption, 3));
        panel.setBounds(10, 47, 414, 74);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 5, 5));
        contentPane.add(panel);

        JLabel calorie_goal = new JLabel("My Calorie Goal");
        calorie_goal.setFont(new Font("Tempus Sans ITC", Font.BOLD, 14));
        panel.add(calorie_goal);

        JTextField goal = new JTextField("1500 calories");
        panel.add(goal);

        JLabel consumed = new JLabel("Consumed");
        consumed.setFont(new Font("Tempus Sans ITC", Font.BOLD, 14));
        panel.add(consumed);

        JTextField total_consumed = new JTextField();
        panel.add(total_consumed);

        JLabel remaining = new JLabel("Remaining");
        remaining.setFont(new Font("Tempus Sans ITC", Font.BOLD, 14));
        panel.add(remaining);

        JTextField total_remaining = new JTextField();
        panel.add(total_remaining);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        panel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(SystemColor.activeCaption, 3, true));
        panel1.setBounds(10, 240, 415, 80);
        contentPane.add(panel1);

        JPanel panel1a = new JPanel();
        panel1a.setBounds(3, 3, 408, 26);
        panel1a.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, 5, 0));
        panel1.add(panel1a);

        JLabel breakfast = new JLabel("Breakfast");
        breakfast.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
        panel1a.add(breakfast);

        //Step 2 - Instantiate combo boxes
        breakfast1 = new JComboBox(breakfast_food1);
        panel1a.add(breakfast1);
        
        breakfast2 = new JComboBox(breakfast_food2);
        panel1a.add(breakfast2);

        breakfast3 = new JComboBox(breakfast_food3);
        panel1a.add(breakfast3);

        JPanel panel1b = new JPanel();
        panel1b.setBounds(3, 33, 410, 45);
        panel1b.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 5, 5));
        panel1.add(panel1b);

        JLabel breakfast_calorie = new JLabel("Recommended Calories");
        breakfast_calorie.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        panel1b.add(breakfast_calorie);

        JTextField breakfast_text = new JTextField();
        breakfast_text.setText("730 calories");
        breakfast_text.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        panel1b.add(breakfast_text);

        JLabel breakfast_consumed = new JLabel("Total Consumed");
        breakfast_consumed.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        panel1b.add( breakfast_consumed);

        totalconsumed = new JLabel("Total consumed is " + total4);
        panel1b.add(totalconsumed);


        breakfast1.addItemListener(this);
        breakfast2.addItemListener(this);
        breakfast3.addItemListener(this);
    }



    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e, JComboBox breakfast1, JComboBox breakfast2, JComboBox breakfast3) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            if(source.equals(breakfast1) || source.equals(breakfast2) || source.equals(breakfast3)) {
                total1 = breakfastcalorie1[breakfast1.getSelectedIndex()];
                total2 = breakfastcalorie2[breakfast2.getSelectedIndex()];
                total3 = breakfastcalorie3[breakfast3.getSelectedIndex()];
                total4 = total1 + total2 + total3;
                totalconsumed.setText("Total consumed is  " + total4);
            };
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainMenu();

    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
       //Step 3 - Trap itemStateChanged from EventListener
       itemStateChanged(e, breakfast1, breakfast2, breakfast3);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried it but the code also do not work still display 0

Comment: I have it working with the source code, updated the answer with the whole class